# Kali Linux Virtual Box not detecting networks with ALFA AWUS036NEH

Tags: wireless-networking, kali-linux, wifi-driver

I am currently running Kali Linux on a virtual box, and I have successfully hooked up my ALFA AWUS036NEH wifi-card to the system, I'm able to scan for networks, but the wifi card never actually picks up any networks. I've tried installing every wifi driver for Linux I could find, I've upgraded and updated the system on numerous occasions, I've tried manually turning on monitor mode, etc. however nothing has worked. If anyone can help it would be extremely appreciated!
[Image of the wifi-card not detecting networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eIek.png)

Comment: I had the same problem and after reading [this discussion](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26545-Kali-detects-USB-wireless-adapter-but-no-wireless-networks-shown) I downloaded an older version of Ubuntu (14.04), which made my AWUS036NEH able to find networks.

Comment: @Tomer do you know what version of Kali would be compatible? And where to download it?

Comment: you can find history of Kali releases [here](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/), I'm not sure which version has kernel version 3.x if any